# Undefined eloquent methods find($id)/all()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try create simple model with Laravel and Eloquent.
Here my code example:

composer.json

```
"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
```

routes.php

```
Route::controller('items', 'ItemsController');
Route::get('item/{item}', array('as'=>'item', 'uses'=> 'ItemsController@getView'));
```

php artisan route:

```
| | GET item/{item}    | item | ItemsController@getView    |    |    |
| | GET items          |      | ItemsController@getIndex   |    |    |
```

controllers/ItemsController.php

```
<?php

class ItemsController extends BaseController {
    public function getIndex()
    {
        $items = Item::all();
        return View::make('items.index')
            ->with('title', 'Index show')
            ->with('items', $items);
    }

    public function getView($id)
    {
        return View::make('items.view')
            ->with('title', 'View show')
            ->with('items', Item::find($id));
    }

}
```

models/Item.php

```
<?php

class Item extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'items';

}
```

DB: I have MySQL table "items" with 6 rows, for example:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | name      | created_at          |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  4 | ironman   | 2012-04-03 10:02:44 |
|  5 | robot     | 2012-04-13 10:02:44 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

When I try to GET mydomain/item/2
Laravel say:

```
Call to undefined method Item::find()
```

And GET mydomain/items/

```
Call to undefined method Item::all()
```

What I'm missed?

Comment: Well are you sure that you are using Eloquent class? I don't know about Laravel but Eloquent class should have the find() and all() methods unless it is defined that you must write those methods. Does Laravel need the `use namespace\Eloquent` sentence?

Comment: Did you do `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Jorge Laravel does it himself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sometimes happens to me when I am changing model and table names "on the fly", and when I do a lot of **migration rollback**. Try to rename you model name, it works for me in most cases.

Comment: Wow, this solved my problem, thanks! That looks like a bug, or maybe it "cache"?

Comment: You nailed it! Excellent